# How to call another class object using literal class in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object-literal

I am trying to create playlist class object from Main class function.

```
function playlist(){
    playlist.prototype.check = function (){
        alert(2);
    };
    this.check();
};

Main = {};//literal class
Main.test = function(){
    var obj  = new playlist();
}
```

Why am I not able to get the alert?

Comment: `Main.test()` triggers the alert, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mark Resolved No Main.test() doesn't trigger the alert.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bFkHA/1/ ;)

Answer (score 1):

*Ok my friend*

There's a simple solution for this
To do it, we need to create the class declaration, then we make a prototype playlist class.

In this example i prefer to use first-capitalize letter on naming class in JS.

```
// Playlist class declaration
function Playlist() {
    // Class properties
    // for example: this.songs = [];
    // for example: this.startingIndex = 0;
}

// Adds extra behavior for Playlist class
Playlist.prototype.check = function () {
    alert(2);
};

// Creates an instance from Playlist
var playlistObj = new Playlist();

// Calls check method.
playlistObj.check();
```

Comment: Thanks, Samuraik. I have already done the experiment of your code ,It works but i want a solution for my code (in the similar approach)